# Shift hours between two dates

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

Input table

```
Start time     End Time
8/12/14 17:00  8/14/14 12:00
```

I need to split the time in shift and show the output as below

```
11:00 to 23:00    23:00 to 11:00
      19                24
```

The calculation work

```
Date     11:00 to 23:00    23:00 to 11:00
8/12/14        6                1
8/13/14        12               12
8/14/14        1                11

Total          19               24
```

Comment: And where does the `19` and `24`come from? Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @juergend Can u look at my updated question ?

Comment: Are these counts of times in that shift? I don't get it. How does your original data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive common table expression to generate the sequence of hours between the start and end dates and then a case statement to evaluate which range it falls into, and then sum to aggregate:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME)
INSERT @T VALUES ('8/12/14 17:00', '8/14/14 12:00')

;WITH cte AS 
    (
    SELECT StartTime AS dt, EndTime
    FROM @T
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 60, dt) AS dt, EndTime
    FROM cte
    WHERE dt < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, EndTime)
    )

SELECT 
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN CAST(dt AS TIME) >= '11:00' AND CAST(dt AS TIME) < '23:00' THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END) AS '11:00 to 23:00',
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN CAST(dt AS TIME) >= '11:00' AND CAST(dt AS TIME) < '23:00' THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
    END) AS '23:00 to 11:00'
FROM cte
```

I'm sure it can be improved but it should give you the desired result.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1b53/5)

Sample output:

```
11:00 to 23:00 23:00 to 11:00
-------------- --------------
19             24
```

This [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d987e0/2) shows handling time in 30 minute intervals, output is:

```
11:00 to 23:00 23:00 to 11:00
-------------- --------------
23.5           25.5
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to calculate the minutes too? I mean the time could be **`18:30`**

Comment: @Luv I added a second fiddle that handles time in 30 minute intervals and includes half hours in the output, was that what you meant?